# Angular UrlMatcher inject Auth Service

Tags: angular, angular-router

We have console with a super admin and organisation admin level. When you login as a super admin, I want the route `/` to go the module for super admin.

```
[super admin]
   + [Organisations]
   + [Users]
   + etc..
```

Routes like `/organisations/list` and `/organisations/Apple/posts` would be achieved when going "into" an Organisation.

When you login as an Organisation admin, the root `/` should load the Organisation module.

```
[org admin]
   + [Posts]
   + [Users]
   + [Events]
   + etc.
```

The problem I am having is that I want to use the URLMatcher to allow 2 modules to be loaded on the same path, based on Authorisation. For that, I have to be able to inject an Auth service into may URLMatcher function.

It seems the UrlMatcher is handled first when a route is evaluated. Using a Resolver is not helping because that happens after.
The only real thing I could do is access LocalStorage and decode the JWT to get authorisation info, but that seems hacky to me.

For now, the only solution I have is to give the super admin its own path `/admin/` and the Org admin the root `/`. Not the end of the world, but it would be nice to be able to have more control with the UrlMatcher.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thinking is to create a wrapper route;

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: WrapperComponent
}
```

`WrapperComponent` can show the relevant views based on the auth.

**WrapperComponent**

```html
<super-admin *ngIf="role == 'superAdmin'; else orgAdmin"></super-admin>

<ng-template #orgAdmin>
  <org-admin></org-admin>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Yeah, we have that as a fallback but that would not be my ideal solution.